# jQuery UI button issue after Chrome update

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

The button radioset is generated like this:

```
var sel = $("<div id='an_options' style='font-size: 10px;float:left;'><input id='single' type='radio' name='aopt' checked='checked' value='1'/><label for='single'>F</label><input id='port_an' type='radio' name='aopt' value='2'/><label for='port_an'>P</label><input id='port_c' type='radio' name='aopt' value='3'/><label for='port_c'>C</label></div> ");   
var container = $("<div class='btn_cont' style='margin-left: 3px;'></div>");
container.append(sel);
$("#an_options").buttonset();
```

Everything has been working fine for years till the latest Chrome update to 33.0.1750.117. Now the button elements are placed on different lines (see pic 1).

So, I open a Chrome developer tool and disable/enable back the "float:left" attribute for the div "#an_options". Everything works fine and the buttonset shows OK (see pic 2).

Pic 1:  [image: corrupted buttonset]   Pic. 2: [image: correct one]

IE and FF render everything fine. Again, the problem started after updating Chrome.... it still shows OK on a previous Chrome version.

Any suggestions?

PS. Still cannot make it work. This is another example:
[image]

As you can see, the bottoms on the right are OK - only buttonsets are broken

Comment: Hi there, can you provide a fiddle? It feels more like a css issue rather than a dom manipulation one.

Comment: one sec -- creating a fiddle...

Comment: Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/yCH5V/
everything works fine in fiddle, but not in my live code

Comment: looks fine to me with that same version of Chrome
http://jsfiddle.net/iGanja/eJcF4/

Comment: have you tried looking at any Chrome extensions that may be causing problems?

Comment: Hm interesting, well considering you managed to get it looking ok here. I am guessing there is parent element in your live code that has a weird css value. Check for widths or display blocks to see if it inheriting anything. Also check if you have any @media overrides. Your code could use some tuning up, but it works in any case. Hope this helps. Can't really help you if we can't see the problem of course :(

Comment: Is the live site available?

Comment: Well, setting a width on btn_cont below 93px will begin to cause the spans to drop. Perhaps you have some parent element restricting the width? Maybe try setting a width on btn_cont.

Comment: I don't see any parent elements that could affect this. Note that it works on any other browsers including a previous version of Chrome. I think the clue is that it works OK, if I disable/enable "float:left" in the Chrome Developer. At the same time, before switching off "float:left", the computed css properties show "float:left"

Comment: The updated fiddle with more parent elements: http://jsfiddle.net/49gXN/
still works fine

Comment: Agree it is strange that all other browsers and earlier versions of Chrome work. That is discouraging. I have also had some strange things happen with some of the recent releases of Chrome. Still the only way I can make it (not) work is to reduce the width of btn_cont.

Comment: Setting the width on an_options seems like a option as well. Good luck.

Comment: thanks - have a look at the last pic of my post. All buttons on the right side are OK (they are inside the btn_cont).

Comment: works well in chrome  33.0.1750.146 on MAC OS/X